# How to run package binary installed with Yarn 2

Tags: typescript, npm, yarnpkg, grpc-node, yarnpkg-v2

I'm giving Yarn 2/Berry a shot and I'm having trouble figuring out how to run a binary installed by a package.

I'm specifically trying to run GRPC typescript compilation. I have the following command in a bash script which works with Yarn 1:

```
yarn run grpc_tools_node_protoc \
    --plugin=protoc-gen-ts=./node_modules/.bin/protoc-gen-ts \
    --ts_out=grpc_js:${PROTO_DEST} \
    --js_out=import_style=commonjs,binary:${PROTO_DEST} \
    --grpc_out=grpc_js:${PROTO_DEST} \
    -I ./protos \
    protos/*.proto
```

But when I move to Yarn 2/Berry I get an error that `./node_modules/.bin/protoc-gen-ts` doesn't exist:

```
./node_modules/.bin/protoc-gen-ts: program not found or is not executable
Please specify a program using absolute path or make sure the program is available in your PATH system variable
--ts_out: protoc-gen-ts: Plugin failed with status code 1.
/Users/paymahn/freenytapp/backend/.yarn/unplugged/grpc-tools-npm-1.11.2-665337de26/node_modules/grpc-tools/bin/protoc.js:41
    throw error;
```

When I run `yarn bin` I see the following:

```
 ❯❯❯ yarn bin
➤ YN0000: eslint
➤ YN0000: grpc_tools_node_protoc
➤ YN0000: grpc_tools_node_protoc_plugin
➤ YN0000: protoc-gen-ts
➤ YN0000: tsc
➤ YN0000: tsserver
➤ YN0000: Done in 0s 19ms
```

and when I run `yarn bin protoc-gen-ts` I see

```
 ❮❮❮ yarn bin protoc-gen-ts
/Users/paymahn/freenytapp/backend/.yarn/cache/grpc_tools_node_protoc_ts-npm-5.3.0-fa422555f1-efcdb0b83f.zip/node_modules/grpc_tools_node_protoc_ts/bin/protoc-gen-ts
```

which tells me that the binary is installed in a zip file (assuming I'm reading it right). How can I "expose" this binary like in classic yarn where it would be located in `node_modules/.bin`?

Comment: Did you manage to make it work ? I am running the same issue.

Comment: @Badr Nope, I switched back to classic yarn